# How do I require padding between arrow function expressions in eslint?

Tags: node.js, eslint

### The Situation

I'm using [ESlint](https://eslint.org/) on a [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org) project and have code that defines a series of arrow function expressions in a row.

```
const x = 15

const foo = () => { ... }

const bar = () => { ... }

const baz = () => { ... }
```

I would like to require white space between ALL of those function expressions (e.g. both before and after each function expression).

### The Question

The closest linting rule I could find was [padding-line-between-statements](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/padding-line-between-statements) with `block-like`.

```
"padding-line-between-statements": [2,
    { "blankLine": "always", "prev": "*", "next": "block-like" },
    { "blankLine": "always", "prev": "block-like", "next": "*" }
]
```

However this also forces padding around `if` blocks (and other block-likes).

For instance, I would like to be able to do:

```
const myCalculatedValue
if (myCalculatedValue > 100) { ... }
```

Is there a way for me to *explicitly* target function expressions through ESLint?  Is this goal achievable without impacting `if` blocks as well?

Comment: Have you tried naming your function expressions and using a `STATEMENT_TYPE` of `function`?

Comment: @morganney Unfortunately (I think) this *is* how you name arrow functions (as opposed to `function whatever() { ...}`) -- that said yes that would work (but for various reasons these need to be arrow functions / function expressions rather than function definitions)

Comment: I would update the question to state that arrow funcs are required. Other than establishing some convention like `const` for function expressions, `let` for everything else (which probably conflicts with other rules), there doesn't seem to be a baked in way to differentiate how you want.

Comment: To be clear, you can write a named function expression like `const foo = function foo() {}`. Now whether ESLint would recognize that as a `function` STATEMENT_TYPE is something I'd have to test.

Comment: @morganney Thank you for that clarification I will definitely make that update to the question (and thank you for the information and advice too!) -- I should note, given that it isn't possible to do what I want please feel free to provide an answer that says as much since that seems to be the correct answer in this case!